# regex : match as much as possible until next match

Tags: html, regex, match

My regex until now:
`<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>(.*?)(?:<h1>)?`

My test String:
`<h1>Foo</h1><h2>Bar</h2><h1>Baz</h1><h3>Test</h3><h1>ghj</h1>zuio`

Right now the part `(.*?)` is matching the shortest String possible, but what I actually want is that it matches everything until the next match (meaning for the first match: `<h2>Bar</h2>`, for the second `<h3>Test</h3>`and so on (underlined in the picture below)).

Can anyone help me?

[Picture of match at:  https://regex101.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcxHQ.png)

Comment: fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/6sNe0b/1

Comment: [Do not use regular expressions to parse/match HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) unless you really really really have to (and are well aware of all implications).

Comment: the html is rendered through markdown and I need a dynamic ToC. So I don't really have a choice there.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=<h1>)(.+?)(?=<h1>)
```

This grabs everything before the next "h1" element, but you could extend it to extract the fields only.

This grabs each field in a list. Could mix the 2 to get groups beginning with h1:

```
(?<=<h\d>)(.+?)(?:<\/h\d>)(?=<h\d>)
```

Comment: That's not quite it, what I need is that the first group gets the content within the <h1></h1> tags and the second group should get anything from the first h1 to the following h1 tag. That should repeat for the whole string if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>((?!<h1>))*`

fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/6sNe0b/5

Das funktioniert jetzt so wie es soll. Trotzdem danke für alle die mit drüber nachgedacht haben.